# Retrofit 2 beta2 failed to do multipart upload

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit beta2 and I'm struggling on multipart upload.  I have tried the code as specified [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server/).  I may have missed something here.

```
public interface SendMediaApiService {
    @Multipart
    @POST(/api/v1/messages)
    Call<ApiResponse> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Query("recipient_user_id") String userId,
            @Query("message") String message,
            @Part("name=\"photo\"; filename=\"selfie.jpg\" ") RequestBody file
    );
}

private void upload() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        // do some stuffs here


    File file = new File(filePath);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    Call<ApiResponse> call = service.upload(token, userId, msg, requestBody);

}
```

when I curl

```
$ curl -v \
> -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" \
> -F "photo=@/path/to/my/image.jpg" \
> http://domain.com/api/v1/messages?recipient_user_id=USER_ID&message=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Little preface: I'm the co-author of the linked blog post.*

Your code looks mostly good. A little difference between our tested code and yours is the `@Part() RequestBody file` declaration. Our code is not specifying the file:

`@Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file`.

In your code, on the other hand, is:

`@Part("name=\"photo\"; filename=\"selfie.jpg\" ") RequestBody file`.

I'd suggest to remove the `name=\"` part from the declaration and try again. If it doesn't help, what's your error?

Comment: you're right @peitek, you'll just have to remove the `name=\"` part

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can delete  **@Multipart**

Just like this,

```
@POST("/V2/image/{type}")
Call<ImageUrl> uploadImg(@Path("type") int type, @Body RequestBody image);
```

To create RequestBody, you can use

```
    public static RequestBody createImageRequest(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", "test.png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())).build();
}
```

When I request with @Multipart, the image file would be put in request body. When without @Multipart, the file in request header.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully uploaded the image file with Retroft.  As what @peitek have suggested to remove the `name=\"` part solved the issue.

For those people that encountered this difficulty, this code below is working (at least for me).  This may serve as your reference.

```
interface SendMediaApiService {
    @Multipart
    @POST(/api/v1/messages)
    Call<ApiResponse> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Query("recipient_user_id") String userId,
            @Query("message") String message,
            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map
    );
}

private void upload() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    // do some stuffs

    Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    File file = new File(path);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
    map.put("photo\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);

    SendMediaApiService service = retrofit.create(SendMediaApiService.class);
    Call<ApiResponse> call = service.upload(token, userId, msg, map);
    call.enqueue(this);
}
```

[source](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063#issuecomment-145920568)